# A decentralized marketplace with Swarm/Whisper and Ethereum Smart Contract

Tags: go-ethereum, swarm, whisper

I was thinking about a workflow where we could use Swarm, Whisper and Ethereum in order to sell any kind of digital data.

I drew a sequence chart and I wanted to have some feedbacks:

[image: sequence chart]

Is there anything that I missed ?

- I know that the file can be decrypted then leaked but that happens with all digital data.

Comment: We are planning to do something similar. If you are interested please contact me on gitter, email, let's collaborate  @david-p